# List Local and Global Key Bindings in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard

Can someone help with a solution to list key bindings being used by an OS X application, as well as global bindings being used by all applications?

Ideally, there would be a way to specify bindings for a single key combination, such as:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

as well as getting a comprehensive text dump of current bindings for all keys.

For my purposes this doesn't need to be fancy: A Bash or AppleScript would be fine. Of course, a dedicated GUI utility would be great, if such a thing exists.

Comment: not sure if this is what you're looking for https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/ but this displays all hotkeys per application

Comment: @PhillPafford: I just downloaded it and CheatSheet is awesome; thanks for the recommendation. IMO it's exactly what the OP (and I) were looking for—not sure why you don't have more upvotes.

Comment: @gravityblack where this has come up for me is when something has started grabbing a keybinding that i don't want. Had a colleague who couldn't type capital "X" for a week, because some random program had decided that was a good start/stop key. It was a service and didn't have a clue what it was except guessing which programs had recent changes. Being able to figure out what's grabbing a keybinding would be a huge troubleshooting boon.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [KeyCue](https://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/), if [CheatSheet](https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/) is not quite enough.

As [Phill](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4432/phill-pafford) already mentioned, CheatSheet is great, because its fast, free and simple. But I noticed that for some applications (like Adobe Photoshop Lightroom) some shortcuts are missing from CheatSheet. KeyCue takes the shortcut game more serious, by showing shortcuts and their context more detailed. It helps you to create your own shortcuts and lets you exactly specify how and when they should trigger.